# Pdf library without acrobat use

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I want my application users to view pdf but without adobe acrobat reader, basically I was looking for a pdf viewer which can work even if there is no pdf tool to view it.

Is there any pdf library to serve this purpose which will be open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking out [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) which is a Javascript library to embed PDFs in HTML files. It handles browser compatibility pretty well and will most likely work on IE8.

In your HTML, you could set up a div to display the PDFs:

```
<div id="pdfRenderer"></div>
```

Then, you can have Javascript code to embed a PDF in that div:

```
var pdf = new PDFObject({
  url: "https://something.com/file.pdf",
  id: "pdfRendered",
  pdfOpenParams: {
    view: "FitH"
  }
}).embed("pdfRenderer");
```

By using [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) you will find all pdf viewer features like navigate to the page etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. Does this need Adobe Acrobat installed?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat does not needs to be installed on client's system

Comment: Thank you for prompt response.